# SVM ground truth image training

Tags: c++, opencv, svm

I am trying to implement a simple demo at the moment, where I will use SVM to be trained with a ground truth image of a kiosk. My plan is to use SVM and openCV to do this. I am doing everything in ubuntu through C++. So these is the basic idea what I'm trying to do:

Load the greyscale image of a kiosk.
Put it in a vector arrangement of pixel intensities to train the SVM
Hence try using another image where this time a person is present in front of the kiosk, and hence when the SVM will be asked to predict wether or not this image's pixel values are within that spectrum, it will say no and hence the kiosk is occupied/being used.

It's a simple start to something I will implement to a larger piece of software where different features will be given.

Comment: What is your question? This seems more like a project proposal.

Comment: Apologies for not making it clear. I am confused as to how I could train the SVM and come up with a decent solution to it. I was wondering if anyone had done something similar as I am looking over the openCV and SVM APIs to understand how I could implement this

Comment: I think you should look at opencv image classification/object detection tutorials. Many use SVM and are designed for a similar use case.

Comment: And don't forget that there's no chance this will work. You need more images and some good features

Comment: Yeah this is for an initial demo. In the future this will be used for videos basically.